# set a specific SSID

Tags: networking, wireless

I recently updated from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 LTS.
My Router is a BT Home Hub 4 which offers

1. BTHub4-HGF6
2. BTEWifi-with-fon
3. BTWifi-X

with 12.04 it always connected to 1 with 14.04 it connects to 2 in about 80% of bootups and I have to change it to 1 manually.

I know I need to put a line such as `SSID='BTHub4-HGF6'`
into a configuration file, but which file? and where? and what is the correct syntax?

Comment: if you open the network settings there should be buttons to change the priority of the network so that `BTHub4-HGF6` is on top

Comment: Do `grep -rH "SSWID='BTHub4-HGF6'" /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

Comment: @Fredca try opening the network settings (I think that's what they're called anyways.... Let me check on that...)

Comment: That didn't work but forgetting the network BTEWifi-with-fon did so soved     heemayl this only returnd netrworks that are no longer available, like coffeee shops

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the question title, because differently from forums on Stack Exchange sites you can have a visual clue of already answered question just by looking at the circle's color on the bottom left side of the question, so adding "Solved" to the title only adds noise when reading it. Instead if you found a solution you can add it as an answer to your own question and mark your answer as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: @Fredca I only commented that because I was unsure I must have been thinking of some other os...  Maybe OS X and Windows do this... regardless you should mark the one by "community wiki"
 as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the connection, and uncheck the option to automatically connect to the undesired SSIDs.

To open the connection editor, either click the applet and choose menu item `Edit connections ...` or open a terminal and type `nm-connection-editor`. Select each of the SSIDs that you *don't* want it to connect to, then choose the `General` tab and uncheck the option:

[image: nm-connection-editor]

[image: connect automatically checked]

[image: connect automatically unchecked]

Answer (score 0):

OP's answer:

> Remove BTEWifi-with-fon SSID from Network Settings solves the problem.